# Is there any residue of $\phi(n)$ that appears only once?

Tags: number-theory

I know there exist (even) residues that do not appear in the sequence [(A005277)](http://oeis.org/A005277), but of those that do, do any appear only once?

Comment: This is a notorious open problem, sometimes referred to as Carmichael's conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture).